# Server issue - I can't access php files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, redhat

I have some issues with my server, for example public_html is my root folder, if I put any php file in root I have this error:

403 Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /check.php on this server.

I try to change permissions on the file is the same. Now the php file is with 0644 permissions
How I can solve this?

Thank you

this is what httpd conf

```
<Directory "/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
                Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/local/apache/htdocs">
    Options All
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Files ~ "^error_log$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all

    Satisfy All
</Files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your public_html folder has 755 permission.

If this doesn't work, check if In your /usr/local/apache/htdocs/httpd.conf settings are like the below

```
<Directory "/usr/local/apache/htdocs">
    Options Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

If the settings are correct there, check your .htaccess file.

Last but not the least. Check if your files and folders have the save usergroup as public_html folder

Comment: Hi thank you i add 755 to public_html folder now I add 777 is the same:

drwxrwxrwx   2 brandnew nobody        4096 Jul 29 18:43 public_html/

Comment: Check if In your /etc/apache2/apache2.conf settings are like this :- <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

Comment: I have cpanel I think the path is not correct, this is the correct path? /etc/httpd/conf/, and for folders I have home/user/

Comment: in cPanel You will find httpd.conf file at /usr/local/apache/conf directory.

Comment: If the settings are correct there, check your .htaccess file.

Comment: i don't understand very well to change what? and in the public_html I don't see any .htaccess file

Comment: I have updated my answer.. Check the httpd.conf that you need to change.

Comment: is the same, now I can't access my url simple

Comment: Can you PM me your ssh details and url to a test file?

Comment: how I can do this? you have an email? or something?

Comment: thank you, I send you the mail with the subject: SSH credentials, please take a look and tell me if everything is okay

Comment: @RobertD Did you check the website link?

Comment: @RobertD : For your non-www domain which is giving error 403 is seems like a DNS error. You DNS record isn't set up to accept traffic to the server without the www. This is a simple A record.

Answer (score 0):

that means you do not have the required permissions to access this file.
open a terminal in that directory and write

```
ls -l check.php
```

If the owner of the file isnt www-data or some server user then you have to change it with

```
chmod 755 check.php
chown www-data:www-data check.php
```